# How to open/display a file from a submenu click in a tkinter?

Tags: file, tkinter, hyperlink, submenu

want to open a text help file for a small desktop app after user click a sub menu.

```
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

tool_menu=Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Tool", menu=tool_menu)
tool_menu.add_command(label="help", command = open("help.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can point the menu callback to a function that opens a new top level window with a disabled Text widget and then insert the contents of the `help.txt` file into the Text widget.

```py
root = Tk()

def open_help_window():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.title("Help")
    text = Text(win)
    with open("help.txt") as help_file:
        text.insert(INSERT, help_file.read())
    text.config(state=DISABLED)
    text.pack()

my_menu = Menu(root)
tool_menu=Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Tool", menu=tool_menu)
tool_menu.add_command(label="help", command = open_help_window)
```